# Azure SQL Managed Instance - SSMS Connectivity

Tags: azure, instance, managed, connectivity

I created a new Azure SQL Managed Instance and obtained the connection string from the Azure Portal.  However, I am unable to connect to the server from SQL Server Management Studio.  The connection hangs and times out with a network error.

Comment: Could you please provide some details about this error?  Maybe an screenshot or something like that

Comment: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 10060)

Comment: Have you whitelisted your public IP in azure portal? If I remember correctly there is a button in azure portal that said something like "add my client IP"

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the public endpoint and ensure you're using the public connection string, including port `3342` at the end of it.

https://www.jamesserra.com/archive/2020/04/accessing-managed-instance-via-ssms/

Comment: Yes the public endpoint has been configure per this article.  Thanks